# Redirect Apache from Default path to specified Directory in Ubuntu Server

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, openerp-7

I have a ubuntu server which has apache2 running in the default path.
when I searched for apache2 it showed me these paths

```
/opt/openerp-7.0-12/apache2/
/etc/init.d/apache2
/etc/logrotate.d/apache2
/etc/default/apache2
/etc/apache2
/usr/sbin/apache2
/usr/lib/apache2
/usr/lib/apache2/mpm-event/apache2
/usr/lib/apache2/mpm-itk/apache2
/usr/lib/apache2/mpm-worker/apache2
/usr/lib/apache2/mpm-prefork/apache2
/usr/share/bug/apache2
/usr/share/doc/apache2.2-common/examples/apache2
/usr/share/doc/apache2
/usr/share/apache2
/var/log/apache2
/var/lib/update-rc.d/apache2
/var/cache/apache2
/run/apache2
/run/lock/apache2
```

Now I have bitnami version of openerp which is in the path "opt/openerp-7.0-12" in which i have apache2 at "opt/openerp-7.0-12/apache2/". 
In this path " opt/openerp-7.0-12/" I have other files for postgresql,python,bitnami,openerp. 
Now how do i redirect the apache2 which is running in the default path to " opt/openerp-7.0-12/apache2/" so that i can access all the files in " opt/openerp-7.0-12/".

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I did not get your question - but if you want to change the default path of apache2 directory - you can change it by editing  etc/apache2/sites-available/default file.  Chenge from "/var/www" to what you want  and restart apache

```
< VirtualHost *:80 >
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

#DocumentRoot /var/www
DocumentRoot /opt/openerp-7.0-12/
<Directory />
```